# C# drawing constituent controls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a custom control, which basically draws a string and a line underneath that string:

```
public class TitleLabel : UserControl  
{
    //Properties here...

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        e.Graphics.DrawString(Caption, Font, brush, 0, 0);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 1, captionSize.Height + 2, this.Width - 1, captionSize.Height + 2);
    }
}
```

This control works fine when placed on a form. However, I need to place it in another usercontrol:

```
public class TitleBox : UserControl
{
    public TitleLabel TitleLabel {get; set;}

    public TitleBox()
    {
        this.TitleLabel = new TitleTable();
        this.TitleLabel.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    }
}
```

However, doing the above doesn't draw the first control. Do I need to hook up its Paint event in the second control?

Comment: I've deleted my answer. Post some short but complete sample which reproduces the problem. That will help us to see what's wrong.

Comment: You probably just need to call Invalidate() on the embedded control from his Parent's paint event.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to create an instance of *TitleLabel* control inside *TitleBox*. Additionally you have to add a newly created control to the *UserControl.Controls* property of *TitleBox* (this property stores a collection of controls contained within a user control), for example:

```
public class TitleBox : UserControl
{
    public TitleLabel TitleLabel {get; set;}

    public TitleBox()
    {
        this.TitleLabel = new TitleTable();
        this.TitleLabel.Location = new Point(10, 10);

        this.Controls.Add(this.TitleLabel);
    }
}
```